# Pulling quotes and authors from websites with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm currently trying to complete the Random Quote Machine project on freecodecamp. The idea is to display the quote and it's author once a user clicks on the "New Quote" button. My issue is that whenever it is clicked, it displays the quote in jibberish and I'm not sure how to correctly pull the quote along with its author. If anyone can guide me on the right path, that would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/leafbow/pen/RyjaeV

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeColor").on("click", function()  {
      getQuote();
    });
});

function getQuote() {
  var options = {
    url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=getQuote'
  };

  var request = $.ajax(options); 

  request.done(function(responseFromServer) {
    console.log(responseFromServer);
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = responseFromServer;
  });

  request.fail(function(responseFromServer, status, error) {
    console.log(responseFromServer);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not jibberish. The server returns the data in JSON, and you will need to parse it to make it work for you.

Try the below code:

```
request.done(function(responseFromServer) {
  var quote = responseFromServer[0];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quote.title;
});
```

Additionally, you need to change the request URL. I got this info by referring to [the docs](https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/).

Remove the `_jsop` parameter from it and add an empty `callback` parameter. So the URL essentially becomes this:

```
https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=
```

See this [working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELQyaB) for more info.